# How to format a file output for a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, file

I have been trying to output a file from a pandas dataframe that looks like this and I have been trying to write it to a file using a different format

```
     codi      Acumulado Ahorro    Prestamo Fondo 1  Prestamo Empresa 1
0    0151           1425.76             28320                0.00
1    2361           1158.49              4100             1200.00
2    2663            737.10              2903              429.00
3    2792            897.75              1950              627.00
4    0737           1266.54              7859                0.00
5    5073            779.00               557              754.00
6    2819           1274.70               958                0.00
7    1558            738.51             10242              676.00
8    4105            695.49              2382                0.00
9    4146           1170.08              8623                0.00
10   0528           1337.17              1042                0.00
```

I tried something like:
`df.to_csv(output_file, sep = '|')`
but the output its just like a csv but instead of "," I get "|"

I'm trying to achieve this output:

```
0E0151
A1425.76|2019|Acumulado Ahorro
A0.00|2019|Prestamo Empresa 1
A28320.00|2019|Prestamo Fondo 1
```

Where 0E has to be concatenated to the number found in column `codi`, then concatenate the letter "A" to the number found in the column `Acumulado ahorro` then the char "|" and the name of the column and so on

How can I create this format so it can be written to an actual file?

Comment: Why don't you just iterate over the dataframe and save the data in the format you need?

Comment: Yeah the best way to go is to get your dataframe in the format you need, then to output it

Comment: because i worked the pandas dataframe to make it look like that it comes from 3 different places and took me my entire life to format it like this as you see im learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very certain that you have to create your own custom formatter. Hopefully this answer provides some guidance.

```py
def format_row(row):
    first_line = f"0E{int(row['codi'])}" + '\n'
    second_line = [f"A{row[el]}|2019|{el}" for el in ['Acumulado Ahorro', 'Prestamo Fondo 1', 'Prestamo Empresa 1']]
    second_line = '\n'.join(second_line)
    return f"{first_line}{second_line}"

format_text = df.apply(format_row, axis=1)

for text in format_text:
    print(text)
```

Output:

```
0E151
A1425.76|2019|Acumulado Ahorro
A28320.0|2019|Prestamo Fondo 1
A0.0|2019|Prestamo Empresa 1
0E2361
A1158.49|2019|Acumulado Ahorro
A4100.0|2019|Prestamo Fondo 1
A1200.0|2019|Prestamo Empresa 1
...
```

You can easily save `format_text` to any text file you want

Comment: This was awesome to implement and easy to understand, i didnt realize i needed further work on the dataframe aswell, like always having 2 decimals and let the codi column be a string because i wanted to preserve the "0"'s at the left, but your answer was super easy to follow and i was able to do those simple fixes.

Answer (score 1):

For such an unusual file format you need a custom writing routine, eg.:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as file:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        file.write("0E" + str(df["codi"][i]) + "\n")
        for c in list(df.columns.values[1:]):
            file.write("A" + str(df[c][i]) + "|2019|" + c + "\n")
```

Comment: cant implement like this because it doesnt come from a single file i actually built this dataframe from different sources inside the code, i think i had to clarify that for starters im sorry :(